# JProgressBar not animating ONLY on Mac with Java 1.7

Tags: java, macos, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

Here's some code that creates and displays a JProgressBar on the EDT. On Apple's Java 6, the progress bar animates. On Oracle's Java 7, it doesn't:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScratchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("java.version = " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("java.vm.version = " + System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

To be precise, I'm using Java 1.7.0_12-ea and OS X 10.8.3.

Can you see something I'm doing wrong? If not, is there a work-around?

**Edit: here's the text output:**

```
java.version = 1.7.0_12-ea
java.vm.version = 24.0-b27
```

**Edit: [it seems to be a known problem](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7168926)**

So now my question is this: how can I work around this problem?

Comment: *"Can you see something I'm doing wrong?"*  It appears fine to my eye.  In fact, that short example and result suggests a bug in the JRE.  Check the [bug DB](http://bugs.sun.com/) for anything similar and possible workarounds.  If nothing found, please raise a new report.

Comment: Could you add the [`java.version`+**`java.vm.version`**](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.version%2Cjava.vm.version&format=TSV) in the output?  I'm not sure if it is necessary, but it cannot hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a confirmed JRE bug, workarounds are going to be pretty hackish.

If you're only using the progress bar in indeterminate mode (in other words, you don't need to show actual progress, just that there's a long-running task), try using [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/)'s JXBusyLabel instead. (Note: good luck finding documentation... all the links seem to be broken nowadays)

If that's not an option, you might try the old VB6 approach of using a timer to periodically force a repaint.  Naiive implementation:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScratchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("java.version = " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("java.vm.version = " + System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

                int delayMilliseconds = 250;
                Timer repaintTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(delayMilliseconds, new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ae) {
                        progressBar.repaint();
                    }
                });
                repaintTimer.start();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

Comment: The forced call to repaint didn't solve the problem - but it is a good idea. Using JXBusyLabel might be a good-enough solution for now. And, as fate would have it, I already have swingx in my project, and all the source and docs for it, including JXBusyLabel.